# Mediawiki Call hook function from another file

Tags: php, function, hook, mediawiki

Hello I need to save some content to database in MediaWiki when a new page is created.
So I added hook in my LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgHooks['PageContentSaveComplete'][] ='assign_responsibility';
```

But I need to call the function assing_responsibility() from a extension php file Responsibility.php not LocalSettings.
I am new at Mediawiki system and I cant find out **How to tell MediaWiki where it can find required hook function**?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hook values are PHP [callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php); they can be defined in any file as long as the file gets loaded before the hook gets called (or, if you use a class method instead of a global function, the class is registered via [$wgAutoloadClasses](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAutoloadClasses)).

The convention is that your extension (which I assume is called Responsibility) creates a hook file:

```
// ResponsibilityHooks.php
class ResponsibilityHooks {
    public static function onPageContentSaveComplete(/*...*/) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
}
```

and makes sure it can be autoloaded:

```
// Responsibility.php
$wgHooks['PageContentSaveComplete'][] = 'ResponsibilityHooks::onPageContentSaveComplete';   
$wgAutoloadClasses['ResponsibilityHooks'] = __DIR__ . '/ResponsibilityHooks.php';
```